# How to get data from parent form component to child component nested components data from parents to children

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I have three Vue components: **FormField.vue**, **GenericForm.vue** (contains `FormField`) and **SignupPage.vue** (contains `GenericForm`)

The **GenericForm.vue** has a **inputFunction** prop which is a function that is passed to it by a child component. It gets executed on button click.

The **SignupPage.vue** has a function **register** which sends a post request to a certain endpoint.

I need to somehow get the data of the fields from the fields in the **GenericForm.vue** so that that data gets sent when the button is clicked when inside **SignupPage.vue** component.

**GenericForm.vue**:

```html
<template>
  <form v-on:submit.prevent="execute()"

        class="signup-form   rounded-lg
              p-10 m-auto  align-middle content-center
              space-y-6
              flex flex-col  items-center justify-center
                ">
    <div class="title-text light-text text-xl">Signup</div>

    <FormField v-for="(field) in fields"
               v-bind:key="field" :placeholder="field"
    />

    <GenericButton :text="buttonText"/>

  </form>
</template>
```

```js
export default {
  components: {GenericButton, FormField, ArticleList},

  props: {
    title: {
      type: String,
      required: true
    },
    fields: {
      type: Array,
      required: true
    },
    buttonText: {
      type: String,
      required: true
    },
    inputFunction: {
      type: Function
    }
  },
...
```

```js
...
  methods: {
    execute() {
      console.log("GenericForm.vue")

      if (this.inputFunction) {
        this.inputFunction()
      }

     },


  }
...
```

**FormField.vue**:

```html
<template>

  <input :placeholder= "placeholder"
      class = "  form-field
            p-2 pl-0  pt-4 pb-2  w-1/3 "

  />

</template>

<script>
export default {
  props: ['placeholder']
}
</script>
```

**SignupPage.vue**:

```
<template>
  <div class=" ">
    <GenericForm title = "Sign Up" button-text= "Sign Up"
             :fields="['Username', 'Email', 'Password']"
             :inputFunction = "register"
    />
  </div>
</template>
```

```
...
  methods:  {
    async register() {
      console.log("register()")
      const response = AuthenticationService.register({
        email: 'wwwwww',
        password: 'frgr'
      }).then((response) => {

        console.log(response)
        console.log(this.$store)
        this.$router.push({
          name: 'ha'
        })
      });
    }
  }
...
```

Comment: You can use props to pass the data from parent to child or can use EventBus when you want to pass data in a multi-level hierarchy. But I think the best way is to go for Vuex.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this, I would name the `input`s, and use [`new FormData()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData/FormData) on the `<form>` element, which would automatically collect all named fields anywhere in the form (even deep nested ones).

1. In `GenericForm.vue`, update the `v-on:submit` value from `execute()` to `execute` (just the method name), so that the `submit`-event data is automatically passed to the handler. We'll use this event data to get the form. Also bind `<FormField>.name` to each `field`.

   ```html
   <template>
     <form v-on:submit.prevent="execute">
       <FormField v-for="(field) in fields" :name="field" />
     </form>
   </template>
   ```
2. Update `execute()` to receive the event data, create the `FormData` from it, and pass the result as an argument to `inputFunction()`:

   ```js
   execute(e) {
     const form = e.target
     const formData = new FormData(form)

     if (this.inputFunction) {
       this.inputFunction(formData)
     }
   }
   ```
3. In `SignupPage.vue`, update `register` to receive the form data:

   ```js
   async register(formData) {
     const email = formData.get('Email')
     const password = formData.get('Password')
     //...
   }
   ```

[demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/getting-fromdata-in-vue-rjmr2?file=/src/views/SignupPage.vue)

Answer (score 1):

you can use reference by path in js objects for sync data in vue like that:

**SignupPage.vue:**

```
data: {
  formData: {}
}
<GenericForm :formData="formData" :fields="['Username', 'Email', 'Password']" />
```

**GenericForm.vue:**

```
props: ['formData']

<FormField v-for="(field) in fields" v-bind:key="field" :field="field" :formData="formData" />
```

**FormField.vue:**

```
props: ['formData', 'field']

<input type="text" v-model="formData[field]" />
```

then you have synced form data in formData Object in signupPage.vue